# Nextjs 13.4 metadata not working with “use client”

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

In my root layout file I export the metadata constant

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Title',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};
```

But it is not working because i have "use client" at the top of the document. But if i remove the "use client", the application starts given an error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
createContext
node_modules\styled-components\dist\styled-components.cjs.js (1:15646)
```

The error is caused by styled-components. How could I resolve this? I can't replace styled-components with css, as the entire application is already in styled-components.

I tried to remove the "use client" from the layout, but the error above started beeping. So I left the "use client", but my metadata is not working